# How to switch views using UIStoryboard and UIViewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm still pretty new to Obj-C and iOS so bear with me. In my app I am trying to implement a share button that brings up a second view in the current view controller. I'm following this tutorial(http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZ3SyGInklQ) and I run into a problem where the dev uses `initWithNibName` and I am using a storyboard. I'm wondering why my second view is not coming up when I press my button. It's probably very obvious but I can't figure it out.

Heres some of my current code:

**Menu.h**

```
//Share button
- (IBAction)shareButton:(id)sender;
```

**Menu.M**

```
- (IBAction)shareButton:(id)sender {

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MenuStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *sharebuttonview = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"sharebuttonview"];


[self presentViewController:sharebuttonview animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

}

Comment: Are you sure that you've got the correct identifier? In your storyboard did you click on the view controller and set the storyboard id?

Comment: Yea my storyboard id is MenuStoryboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you go into the storyboard and then you connect the Share Button with the View you want to show. After that you name this segue with an Identifier.

In you Menu.M in the IBAction you write:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegueIdentifier" sender:self];
```

(mySegueIdentifier is the Identifier you used before)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of the issue it appears that you may want to do a manual segue, which allows you to open a target view controller from any number of UI controls. The workflow has changed from Xcode 5 compared to prior versions of Xcode. You may want to see my blog post for additional [tips](https://plus.google.com/+TommieNCarterJr/posts/Fb8vmCuWHos) but essentially you will want to open your storyboard and do a Ctrl+Drag from one view controller in the document outline view to a second view controller.

Then you will need to name the segue that is created by clicking the Segue in the middle of the gray line connecting the two view controllers and update the segue id in the identity inspector.

In your source view controller you should be able to have any action call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegueID"];`

Additionally, you can add a prepareForSegue method to the source view controller, which allows you to initialize and pass information to the target view controller.

Apple has a sample project that you can download to see this workflow in detail ([MultipeerGroupChat](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/samplecode/MultipeerGroupChat/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013691))

Hope this helps.

Comment: instead of doing the Ctrl+Drag from one viewcontroller to the next can I do the Ctrl+Drag from a button to a viewcontroller

Comment: @ErvNoel - Not in Xcode 5. There is no longer a way to drag from button to the vc. The current correct method lets you drag between vc to vc and reference the named segue using the performSegueWithIdentifier... in your action method for the buttons.